# file upload integrity check

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have file uploads in a form like photo or some other documents. Sometimes the file get uploaded ie,the file path will be there but the size will be 0 bytes or a part file. Please suggest me a solution to check the complete integrity check for such uploads. 
I have one solution to find the file size and check it after upload complete,  is this a reliable solution?, any other good methods?

Comment: do you know why it's length 0 or a partial file?  Did an exception get thrown by the Stream you were using to save the file from the request?

Comment: @tim_yates It may be due to some internet connection issues or other transmission issues

Comment: Yeah, but you don't get an exception?  If their end of the socket goes away, then it should exit with an exception shouldn't it?

Comment: @tim_yates there is no such exceptions and the form get submitted successfully with sometimes such a part file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finding the size is not a completely reliable solution. I would recommend you to use [checksum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum) for checking the integrity of file transferred. Client should calculate the checksum of file it is sending, send the checksum value with the request as a param. On the server side, again checksum should be calculated and compared against the checksum sent by the client. If two matches, file is good!

Here is a sample to generate checksum in java:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-generate-a-file-checksum-value-in-java/

Comment: @Nizil Checksum is handled by TCP for the TCP packet and not for the file sent through java.

Comment: Well, the question is: if all the packet are not corrupted, and all the packet are received (TCP ack)... How can we get a corrupted file ?